# What is the word for converting integer to decimal or continuous number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, real-numbers, interval-arithmetic

You say "discretize" when you make a continuous number a number of discrete steps. Now I am looking at it the other way round.

I am looking for the mathemetical word that explains how I change an integer ordinal scale to ordinal scale or interval scale of decimal (1.) or continuous (2.) values.

For example, inventing some words here:

1. decimal:

   - decimalize (decimal number, limited after the comma)

     This would fit perhaps if I just add more discrete steps (that is,
     allowing a 4.1 instead of a 4 as well, but not a 4.1234 to infinite
     steps after the comma).
2. continuous:

   - continuize
   - realize (to real number),
   - floatize (to floating number)

I would like to say one word for the change from integers in a questionnaire into proper interval data, which is done by the Item Response Model (latent trait measurement), see [How to transform ordinal data from questionnaire into proper interval data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27927/how-to-transform-ordinal-data-from-questionnaire-into-proper-interval-data). It might also fit to the second answer there, linking to [Using ridits to assign scores to categories of ordinal scales](http://statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/using-ridits-to-assign-scores-to-categories-of-ordinal-scales/).

For example, you have a questionnaire which has only 1 to 5 in discrete integer steps.

How would you call it, if it has to become discrete in decimals:

```
1, 1.1, 1.2 ... 4.9, 5
```

How would you call it if it has to become continuous:

```
1, 1.0x, 1.1x ... 4.9x, 5
with x being further numbers, up to infinite length.
```

Comment: 'interpolation' perhaps? The question is not quite clear.

Comment: @JairTaylor "interpolation" is in the right direction I think, it could even be right? I am not an English native, though. By the way, it is possible that these words do not exist. "discretize" is something you can easily understand. The other way round, it is almost magic to get there.

Comment: @JairTaylor Merriam-Webster dictionary: "Interpolate" definition is - to alter or corrupt (something, such as a text) by inserting new or foreign matter; Cambridge dictionary: 1. to add something in the middle of a text, piece of music, etc.; 2. to add a number or item into the middle of a series, calculated based on the numbers or items before and after it. Though there are a bit more tricks to do here over the full dataset, it seems as if it is what is needed. Would be accepted, I would not mind a one-word answer.